Could someone please correct this paragraph for me?
여자 목소리 있는 남자는 조금 무서워지? 비디어 봤고 넷카마에 대해서 배웠고 아 이게 무섭다고 생각했더니 게임하면서 여자갈은 한 명의 남자를 만났는 적을 기억했습니다. 그때 와 이 사람은 완전 여자같은데 저는 그렇게 여자 목소리 있으면 돈을 얼마나 벌 수 있냐고 긍굼했습니다. 이 사람들을 싫어하는 의미는 아닙니다. 오히려 제가 사실 그들을 존경합니다. 그런데, 제가 제일 좋아하는 버튜버가 실제로 남자 라는 사실이 조금 즐겁다는 것 같습니다.
I wrote this paragraph and posted it to a discord server and it was said that I should get multiple people to correct it so that I can learn more effectively. What mistakes did I make and what should I do to avoid making those same mistakes in the future?

여자 목소리 있는 남자는 조금 무서워지? 비디어 봤고 넷카마에 대해서 배웠고 아 이게 무섭다고 생각했더니 게임하면서 여자갈은 한 명의 남자를 만났는 적을 기억했습니다. 그때 와 이 사람은 완전 여자같은데 저는 그렇게 여자 목소리 있으면 돈을 얼마나 벌 수 있냐고 긍굼했습니다. 이 사람들을 싫어하는 의미는 아닙니다. 오히려 제가 사실 그들을 존경합니다. 그런데, 제가 제일 좋아하는 버튜버가 실제로 남자 라는 사실이 조금 즐겁다는 것 같습니다.
->
여자 목소리를 내는 남자는 조금 무섭죠? 영상을 보고 넷카마에 대해 알게 됐고, "아, 이거 무섭다"라는 생각이 들었습니다. 게임하면서 만난 어떤 사람을 여자로 착각한 적이 있습니다. 그때 "와, 이 사람은 완전 여자 같은데"라는 생각이 들었고, 저는 그 정도로 여자처럼 목소리를 낼 수 있으면 돈을 얼마나 벌지 궁금했습니다. 이 사람들을 싫어하는 건 아닙니다. 저는 그들을 존중합니다. 다만, 제가 제일 좋아하는 버튜버가 실제로 남자라는 사실이 조금 재미있는 것 같습니다.

be careful of the collocation like "목소리를 내다"

nuance in the meaning of the verb


배웠고 -> 알게 됐고 // 그들을 존경합니다. -> 그들을 존중합니다. // 즐겁다는 -> 재밌다는

nuance in the meaning of a verb ending(어미)

만났는 적 -> 만났던 적..
벌 수 있냐고 -> 벌 수 있을지
